# Using jQuery along custom javascript files in angular 6

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, components

I have this myjs.js file

```
function slide_down(id) {
    $('#' + id).slideToggle();
}
function open_team_info(id) {
    $('#team-info-' + id).css("visibility", "visible");
    $('#team-info-' + id).css("opacity", "1");
}
function close_team_info(id) {
    $('#team-info-' + id).css("visibility", "hidden");
    $('#team-info-' + id).css("opacity", "0");
}
```

I want to use this functions in terms of

> (click)=a_function('someID')

in HTML

How can I include this functions in my component from myjs.js file?

In other words, is there any relevant solution as we do in plain HTML project like:

```
<script src="myjs.js"></script>
```

PS: I got 5 days with Angular so any Hint or suggestion will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used the Angular-Cli to create the Angular Project. Then you could create an `myjs.ts` file inside the `src` folder.

Then, in order to use those function, you have to export them first, like this:

```js
export function fslideDown(id) {
  $('#' + id).slideToggle();
}
export function open_team_info(id) {
  $('#team-info-' + id).css('visibility', 'visible');
  $('#team-info-' + id).css('opacity', '1');
}
export function close_team_info(id) {
  $('#team-info-' + id).css('visibility', 'hidden');
  $('#team-info-' + id).css('opacity', '0');
}
```

Inside any component file, you may import them like this:

```
import { close_team_info, fslideDown, open_team_info } from '../../myjs';
```

Then using it as normal functions.

Hopefully, it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Normally jquery is not preferable in angular. Instead You can simply use

**class binding** or **style binding** in angular. if you need you can simple declare the jquery element in your component

```
declare var $: any
```

for example in your div tag use like this

```
<div [style.visibilty] = "visible">
</div>
```

**or**

```
<div [ngStyle] = "myclass">
</div>
```

and in your ts file you can make a binding option

```
visible = "hidden";
myclass = {
   "visibility" : this.visible,
}
```

if you are using seprate file for these scripts means you can use import option to use the the file

```
import { examplefunction } from '../../service/myjs.ts';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you used Angular-Cli so you have an angular.json file in root directory of the project and you can import custom styles and script files into your project by referencing them in this file.
for example for script files you should write the path to the file in "script" section:

```
"scripts": [
  "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
  "PathToFile/myjs.js"
]
```